# Protected field alternatives in Java?

Tags: java, protected

I have a code using protected field in super class. How can I avoid it, because I think all field should be private?

```
 /** "Abstract Builder" */
 abstract class PizzaBuilder {
    protected Pizza pizza;

    public Pizza getPizza() { return pizza; }
    public void createNewPizzaProduct() { pizza = new Pizza(); }

    public abstract void buildDough();
    public abstract void buildSauce();
    public abstract void buildTopping();
 }

 /** "ConcreteBuilder" */
 class HawaiianPizzaBuilder extends PizzaBuilder {
    public void buildDough()   { pizza.setDough("cross"); }
    public void buildSauce()   { pizza.setSauce("mild"); }
    public void buildTopping() { pizza.setTopping("ham+pineapple"); }
 }

 /** "ConcreteBuilder" */
 class SpicyPizzaBuilder extends PizzaBuilder {
    public void buildDough()   { pizza.setDough("pan baked"); }
    public void buildSauce()   { pizza.setSauce("hot"); }
    public void buildTopping() { pizza.setTopping("pepperoni+salami"); }
 }
```

Comment: You can best avoid this problem by changing your thinking. There's nothing wrong with using protected fields the way they're intended to be used.

Comment: Can you code a setter and getter in the super class, then use super.getter method to access them?

Comment: @MichaelMyers: thanks for your answer. But this code allow all classes in the same package access this protected field and it may be dangerous.

Comment: @Logan: thanks for your answer, but all classes can access this field via setter/getter method. But I think this solution is better the original.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `getPizza()` in the child classes.

so :

```
 public void buildDough()   { pizza.setDough("cross"); }
```

becomes

```
public void buildDough()   { getPizza().setDough("cross"); }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always make Hawaiian and Spicy pizza builders public and Pizza field protected.

```
public abstract class PizzaBuilder {
    protected Pizza pizza;
    ...
 }

 /** "ConcreteBuilder" */
 public class HawaiianPizzaBuilder : PizzaBuilder {
     ...
 }

 /** "ConcreteBuilder" */
 public class SpicyPizzaBuilder : PizzaBuilder {
     ...
 }
```

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. The private 'pizza' member would not be accessible by HawaiianPizzaBuilder or SpicyPizzaBuilder without some sort of access, be it protected, or getter/setter methods.

Comment: Right, I meant protected. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You respond to a comment thus:

> @Logan: thanks for your answer, but all classes can access this field via setter/getter method. But I think this solution is better the original.

If you want to stop that, then maybe the answer is to change the visibility of the getter method, and not provide a setter at all.

---

Actually, the overall design looks a bit odd.  You've got a `create` method that doesn't return the object that it creates, and no obvious way for the subclasses' build methods to be called.  (Perhaps you should "review" the Factory Object design pattern.)

A re-think at this level would make it clear that the `pizza` variable and its getter can and should be hidden from outside view.